# ¿Cambiar el formato de fecha y hora en antes de serealizar Json?

Tags: json, windows-forms, serialización

Tengo mi boton que serializa mi objeto que lo utilizo de estamanera:

```
 private void btnJson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OleDbConnection connection = MSAConnection.getConnection();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Persona";
                OleDbDataAdapter d = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                d.Fill(ds,"Persona");
                string n = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
                textBox1.Text = n;
            }
```

todo va bien.

***esto es lo que me muestra:***

```
{
  "Persona": [
    {
      "Id": 777,
      "nombreCompleto": "CARLOS MANUEL",
      "fecha": "2018-03-01T00:00:00",
      "hora": "1899-12-30T15:43:35"
    }
  ]
}
```

***quiera saber si hay forma de serializarlo asi:***

```
{
  "Persona": [
    {
      "Id": 777,
      "nombreCompleto": "CARLOS MANUEL",
      "fecha": "2018-03-01",
      "hora": "15:43:35"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formatea tu dato en tu consulta:

```
select
      Id,
      nombreCompleto,
      Format(fecha, 'Short Date') as fecha,
      Format(hora, 'Short Time') as hora
from Persona
```